# Cannot create Wikidata schema in OpenRefine

Tags: wikidata, openrefine

Would anyone know why I cannot create a Wikidata schema in OpenRefine? I've reconciled all columns necessary for the project, but when I go to the schema tab, no column will drag/drop into the boxes.
[stubbon schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtn6P.jpg)
Thank you!
J

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar problems, and would bet there is an error message in your browser's javascript console.

What worked for me was removing and re-adding the label and description fields/boxes in the schema. If that doesn't help, continue to remove other parts of the scheme. Even reloading the page might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bug. Please [open a bug report](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/new/choose) with as much detail as possible, including any error messages from your browser's Javascript console, as suggested by @Mathias, or the server log. If the project is not sensitive, please provide it as well.